# Using Wix to create a database in LocalDB

Tags: wix, localdb

I'm trying to use Wix to create a database in LocalDB, but I'm not sure of the connection string to use (or if it is even possible). At the moment I have done some Googling and found that in Wix 3.6 the ODBC driver for LocalDB was not supported. However, I am using Wix 3.8.

I currently have my Wix bundle installing LocalDB, then it runs my own custom msi to install all of my required files, and then it's running a second custom msi which should create the database and all of the required tables. This second custom msi is where it is failing.

I have tried the following, but neither have worked:

```
<sql:SqlDatabase Id="SqlDatabase" Database="DbName" Server="localdb" 
Instance="V11.0" CreateOnInstall="yes" DropOnUninstall="yes">
```

And

```
<sql:SqlDatabase Id="SqlDatabase" Database="DbName" Server="(localdb)\V11.0" 
CreateOnInstall="yes" DropOnUninstall="yes">
```

I am referencing `WixSqlExtension.dll` and I have included the namespace at the top of my wxs file.

Anyone had any success using LocalDB with Wix?